# Unable to build NetBeans C/C++ Project

Tags: c++, netbeans, build

I just can't build a C/C++ project in NetBeans. The `environment variable` is properly set.
[image]

Error :

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=            SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
 make.exe[1]: Entering directory   `/c/Users/Rahul/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
 "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk  dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
  make.exe[2]: Entering directory  `/c/Users/Rahul/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
  mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
  make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found
  make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127
  make.exe[2]: Leaving directory  `/c/Users/Rahul/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
  make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
  make.exe[1]: Leaving directory  `/c/Users/Rahul/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
  make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

  BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
printf("hello");
return 0;
}
```

NetBeans-1 :
[image]

NetBeans-2 :

[image]

Comment: Did you try to move MinGW settings in the beginning of your PATH?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "make" from msys looks for the msys mkdir but can't find it because you are not running in an msys environment.

The safe way to solve this is to launch NetBeans from the msys shell.

Alternatively you can manually create the directory as gcc/g++/... itself is also found on the path outside of an msys environment.