# netbeans c++ mingw - no shell found

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I have netbeans IDE v8.2 . Im trying to create a C++ project. I dont have cygwin, but I have already installed MinGW, inside it, i have msys-make.bin, mingw32-gcc-g++.bin. Also, when i installed mingw, it came with nysys 1.0.

This is the tools options table:[image]

However, it keep sending the message "no shell found. Cannot proceed. Please install either cygwin or mysys".

What is the solution for this?

Comment: The error message seems clear, install MSYS.

Comment: @john  But isnt msys automatically installed when i install mingw ? i have msys 1.0 already inside mingw

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097448/unable-to-build-netbeans-c-c-project as might a google search. You're not the only person with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@john I think that i solved it. Yes, minGW has msys 1.0, but i installed mysys standalone version in c:\ and netbeans worked with it. It now seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve it if we set as environment variables **[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)** (C:\MinGW\bin) and **[MySYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)** (C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin).

[image: Environment variables]

This is my current setup:

[image: Netbeans configuration]